Accessing a local Postgre DB from Kubernetes
I am new to Kubernetes and currently doing some testing using Virtualbox, in Virtualbox, I have created 2 Kubernetes cluster with 1 Master and 1 worker. One Postgresql being installed a my local PC.
I have a simple MVC app based on mvcmovie from Microsoft but uses Postgresql through a connection string. I have created a docker image of the app, and tested working with Docker Desktop, the container is able to load the page and retrieve data from Postgresql. The build image is uploaded to Docker Hub.
I am able to pull the image using the deployment below
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ryur-code
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ryur-code
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ryur-code
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: ryur-code
        image: ryur/kube_test
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred
---

kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ryur-code
spec:
  selector:
    app: ryur-code
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
  type: NodePort

Services
postgre.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgre
spec:
  selector:
    app: ryur-code
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 5432
      targetPort: 5432
  externalIPs:
    - 192.168.68.107


postgre2.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgresql
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - port: 5432
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: postgresql
subsets:
  - addresses:
        - ip: 192.168.68.107
    ports:
      - port: 5432
        name: postgresql

I am able load the main page, however, it will give me an "error occurred while processing your request", if I am trying to access the postgre database.
I have tried with the postgre.yaml and also postgre2.yaml, both not working, also tried a number of services. Again, the postgre DB sits in 192.168.68.107 local DB, is not part of of the Kubernetes cluster.
Note: I have also include all the IPs there is into pg_hba.conf, including ,host all all 0.0.0.0/0 scram-sha-256
from the VM, I am also able to ping the PC localhost where the postgre database is located. No firewall is present.
Honestly stumped if I am doing this correctly, appreciate your help and feedback.
enter image description here

What will the eventual deployment look like; where will the database be running when you push this out for real?  Can you move the database into a container, with its own StatefulSet and Service?

Hi David, thanks for the question, the final deployment, I was thinking to maintain it as stateless as possible, therefore, Kubernetes cluster will host only app images, and the database outside this cluster. Kinda not wanting to maintain any persistent volumes.

You can access services running on your local machine from a Pod by adding the following:
spec:
  hostNetwork: true

Details can be found here: hostNetwork:
Host networking requested for this pod. Use the host's network namespace.

This will look on whichever random node the Pod happens to be running on; there most likely isn't a non-container database running there.  Local policy may also disallow using this.

But it is exactly whats stated in the question, "Again, the postgre DB sits in 192.168.68.107 local DB, is not part of of the Kubernetes cluster." -> I agree, It's a weird setup and I wouldn't recommend a setup like this, none the less it should work.

thanks Si90, I will try it out. Also what would you recommend for the database setup? Is it better to include this into the kubernetes cluster? The thought process was I can place the database anywhere cloud or local and be accessible from any kubernetes cluster.

If you use Kubernetes in a cloud environment, your hyperscaler usually also provides kubernetes operators, that make database integration very easy, if you want to use their database service as well.
If you put the database into the cluster, it's easy to create a service that makes it accessible from all nodes.
Otherwise you could also try this, to keep the database external: https://medium.com/@ManagedKube/kubernetes-access-external-services-e4fd643e5097

Apologies for the late reply, @Si90 will try out the hostnetwork, and thanks for the info.

Hi All, added the hostnetwork and currently the pod is able to connect to the postgre. Thanks everyone for your help.
